# SQL INDEX - how it works?

Tags: index

My knowledge of **databases** and **SQL** is based in most on university classes. Anyhow, I spent few monts (almost a year) in a company, where I was working with databases.

I have read few books and I have taken part in few trainings about databases such as `MySQL`, `PostgreSQL`, `SQLite`, `Oracle` and also few `nonSQL` `db`s such us `MongoDB`, `Redis`, `ElasticSearch` etc.

As well as I said, I am begginer, with a lot of lacks of knowledge but today, someone told something, what is totally against my begginer's knowledge.

Let me explain. Let's take **SQL** database and create simple table `Person` with few records inside:

```
id | name   | age
-----------------
1  | Alex   | 24
2  | Brad   | 34
3  | Chris  | 29
4  | David  | 28
5  | Eric   | 18
6  | Fred   | 42
7  | Greg   | 65
8  | Hubert | 53
9  | Irvin  | 17
10 | John   | 19
11 | Karl   | 23
```

Now, it's the part, I would like to focus on - `id` is the `INDEX`.

So far, I thought it works in this way: when a table is being created the `INDEX` is empty. When I am adding new record to my table the `INDEX` is being recalculated based on some alghortims. For example:

Grouping one by one:

```
1    ... N
N+1  ... 2N
     ...
XN+1 ... (X+1)N
```

so, for my example with `size = 11 elements` and `N = 3` it will be like this:

```
id | name   | age
-----------------
1  | Alex   | 24     // group0
2  | Brad   | 34     // group0
3  | Chris  | 29     // group0
4  | David  | 28     // group1
5  | Eric   | 18     // group1
6  | Fred   | 42     // group1
7  | Greg   | 65     // group2
8  | Hubert | 53     // group2
9  | Irvin  | 17     // group2
10 | John   | 19     // group3
11 | Karl   | 23     // group3
```

So, when I am using query `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE id = 8` it will do some simple calculation `8 / 3 = 2`, so we have to look for this object in `group2` and then this row will be returned:

```
8  | Hubert | 53
```

[image]

This approach works in time `O(k)` where `k << size`. Of course, an alghoritm to organise rows in groups is for sure much more complicated but I think this simple example shows my point of view.

So now, I would like to present another approach, which has been showed me today.

Let's take once again this table:

```
id | name   | age
-----------------
1  | Alex   | 24
2  | Brad   | 34
3  | Chris  | 29
4  | David  | 28
5  | Eric   | 18
6  | Fred   | 42
7  | Greg   | 65
8  | Hubert | 53
9  | Irvin  | 17
10 | John   | 19
11 | Karl   | 23
```

Now, we are creating something similar to `Hashmap`(in fact, literally it is a Hash Map) which maps `id` to `address` of row with this id. Let's say:

```
id | addr 
---------
1  | @0001
2  | @0010
3  | @0011
4  | @0100
5  | @0101
6  | @0110
7  | @0111
8  | @1000
9  | @1001
10 | @1010
11 | @1011
```

So now, when I am running my query: `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE id = 8`

it will map directly `id = 8` to address in memory and the row will be returned. Of course complexity of this is `O(1)`.

So now, I have got few questions.

**1. What are the adventages and disadventages of both solutions?**

**2. Which one is more popular in current database implementations? Maybe different dbs use different approaches?**

**3. Does it exist in nonSQL dbs?**

Thank you in advance

---

### COMPARISON

```
               |      B-tree     |   Hash Table
----------------------------------------------------
----------------   one element   -------------------
----------------------------------------------------
SEARCHING      |  O(log(N))      | O(1) -> O(N)  
DELETING       |  O(log(N))      | O(1) -> O(N)
INSERTING      |  O(log(N))      | O(1) -> O(N)
SPACE          |  O(N)           | O(N)
----------------------------------------------------
----------------    k elements   -------------------
----------------------------------------------------
SEARCHING      |  k + O(log(N))  | k * O(1) -> k * O(N)
DELETING       |  k + O(log(N))  | k * O(1) -> k * O(N)
INSERTING      |  k + O(log(N))  | k * O(1) -> k * O(N)
SPACE          |  O(N)           | O(N)
```

N - number of records

Am I right? What about cost of rebuilding **B-tree** and **Hash table** after each **insert/delete**? In case of **B-tree** we have to change some pointers but in case of **balanced b-tree** it needs more effort. Also in case of **Hash table** we have to do few operation, especially, if our operation generate **conflicts**.

Comment: In the second way, you are describing a hash index.  The part about `O(1)` you got it right!  In the first way, it seems you are describing a B-tree index but you have some misunderstanding. There is no calculation (division by 3 or anything), it's more complex as the tree has more levels (it's a tree, it has big, small, smaller branches, ..., and then leaves :)

Comment: BTrees: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree surprised there wasn't an algorithms course at your university that explained this

Comment: @ypercube Hi, thank you for your answer. As well as I wrote: `Of course, an alghoritm to organise rows in groups is for sure much more complicated but I think this simple example shows my point of view.` Of course, I know it is much much much more complicated. So finally, when I am saying in my code `INDEX` which of my solutions (**1st** or **2nd**) is closer to this real one? And what about time needed to access a record based on `INDEX`. Is it really `O(1)`? With B-tree index it sounds much like `O(log2(N))`. Am i right?

Comment: @FreshPhilOfSO I guess (even more, I am sure) it was some lectures about that. Probably, I missed something...

Comment: ElasticSearch uses inverted indexes, totally different than B-trees https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-from-the-bottom-up

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're basically describing a B-tree index and a hash index.  They both have a place, but both are best suited for different jobs.

### Advantages and disadvantages

B-tree (and B+-tree) indexes are usually balanced.  This means that looking for a value will always take the same amount of time no matter where in the tree it falls (O(log n)).  Generally, the number of levels in the tree is limited, so it tends to get "wider" not "deeper".  For small data sets, the cost of maintaining and using the B-tree, however, can be more than just reading all the rows.  B-tree indexes are good for large data sets, data sets with low selectivity, or data sets where you intend to select a range of objects not just one object.

Hash tables are great for small data sets.  Hash indexes have a predefined number of hash buckets, depending on the hashing algorithm used.  This is because a given hash algorithm can only produce so many unique hashes, so it only gets "deeper" not "wider".  Once the database engine finds the right bucket, it then walks through all the objects in that bucket to find the one you want.  With small, highly selective data sets each bucket contains a very small number of objects and is resolved pretty quickly.  With larger data sets, the buckets get much more crowded.  So, if the object you need is in a small bucket or is near the beginning of the bucket, it returns pretty quick.  If it's at the end of a large bucket, it takes longer.  The index is not balanced, so the performance is anywhere from O(1) to O(n).

### Popularity

In general, I've run across B-trees the most.  Bitmap indexes are also another option for values with a low cardinality (think booleans or maybe gender).  This is going to vary depending on your database engine as to what index types are available.

### NoSQL

NoSQL databases definitely support indexes.  Most support B-tree or a variation on B-tree.  Most seem to support hashed indexes as well.

Comment: I don't think that the number of levels in B+ trees is fixed. At least not in SQL-Server as far as I know.

Comment: That's true.  A B-tree could have any number of levels, but it is generally limited to 3 or 4.  I edited my answer.

Comment: Hi @sarme. I really like your answer. It explains a lot. Don't you mind if I start bounty for this question? Maybe someone will add something interesting.

Comment: Dont you mean low cardinality for bitmap index?

Comment: Right, LOW cardinality.  I have to stop answering questions just before bed time :).  Answer updated.

Comment: Hi, I added **comparison** of `BTree` and `Hash Table`. Could you check, if it is correct? I also asked another question. Thanks in advance. Do not hesitate to edit my post and put proper values.

Comment: @sarme you wrote `Hash indexes have a predefined number of hash buckets`. What about `Dynamic Hashing`? Does it also work in this way with this way of hashing? I read this article http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/dbms_hashing.htm. That's why I am asking this question.

Comment: @Girly Girl.  That could be a whole new question on its own.  Hard to answer in a comment.  Dynamic hash indexes still have the same basic properties of a hash index.  They are, however, more efficient because you don't have to allocate all the buckets up front and the keys can be adjusted as the selectivity of your data changes.  The number of total buckets is still finite and the distribution still depends largely on your hashing algorithm.  Here's a nice demo:  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TtkN2xRAgv4)

Answer (score 4):

What are the adventages and disadventages of both solutions?
The second solution can not perform range scans. It is great for selecting a single ID. But what if you want ids 3 through 8? It has to grab all the records individual which in the real world isn't just O(1) * 6 records to retrieve. In a large, production database with a HashMap index you would get records on different pages, requiring you to hit the disk and read six different pages into memory.

In a B-Tree structure, like how your first situation would actually be implemented, the ids would be sequential on disk and a single page would likely hold ids 3 - 8 increasing the speed of range scans will making individual access O(log n).

Which one is more popular in current database implementations? Maybe different dbs use different approaches?
I don't have a huge experience in lots of different databases. I know Sql Server uses B-Trees mostly, but SQl 2014 has some new Hash Indexes you can use on certain table. I hear a lot of No Sql databases and caching databases built on retrieving individual records use hash indexes as well. This makes sense for caches since you want the record for user A Page 11 and don't need range scans.

Does it exist in nonSQL dbs? Yes. Taking a quick look at the create index documentation for postgressql I see it supports both Hash and B-Tree indexes as well as a few others.