# SQL INDEX - how it works?

Tags: index

### See this question here: [Database Administrators meta](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/62576/36686)

My knowledge of **databases** and **SQL** is based in most on university classes. Anyhow, I spent few monts (almost a year) in a company, where I was working with databases.

I have read few books and I have taken part in few trainings about databases such as `MySQL`, `PostgreSQL`, `SQLite`, `Oracle` and also few `nonSQL` `db`s such us `MongoDB`, `Redis`, `ElasticSearch` etc.

As well as I said, I am begginer, with a lot of lacks of knowledge but today, someone told something, what is totally against my begginer's knowledge.

Let me explain. Let's take **SQL** database and create simple table `Person` with few records inside:

```
id | name   | age
-----------------
1  | Alex   | 24
2  | Brad   | 34
3  | Chris  | 29
4  | David  | 28
5  | Eric   | 18
6  | Fred   | 42
7  | Greg   | 65
8  | Hubert | 53
9  | Irvin  | 17
10 | John   | 19
11 | Karl   | 23
```

Now, it's the part, I would like to focus on - `id` is the `INDEX`.

So far, I thought it works in this way: when a table is being created the `INDEX` is empty. When I am adding new record to my table the `INDEX` is being recalculated based on some alghortims. For example:

Grouping one by one:

```
1    ... N
N+1  ... 2N
     ...
XN+1 ... (X+1)N
```

so, for my example with `size = 11 elements` and `N = 3` it will be like this:

```
id | name   | age
-----------------
1  | Alex   | 24     // group0
2  | Brad   | 34     // group0
3  | Chris  | 29     // group0
4  | David  | 28     // group1
5  | Eric   | 18     // group1
6  | Fred   | 42     // group1
7  | Greg   | 65     // group2
8  | Hubert | 53     // group2
9  | Irvin  | 17     // group2
10 | John   | 19     // group3
11 | Karl   | 23     // group3
```

So, when I am using query `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE id = 8` it will do some simple calculation `8 / 3 = 2`, so we have to look for this object in `group2` and then this row will be returned:

```
8  | Hubert | 53
```

[image]

This approach works in time `O(k)` where `k << size`. Of course, an alghoritm to organise rows in groups is for sure much more complicated but I think this simple example shows my point of view.

So now, I would like to present another approach, which has been showed me today.

Let's take once again this table:

```
id | name   | age
-----------------
1  | Alex   | 24
2  | Brad   | 34
3  | Chris  | 29
4  | David  | 28
5  | Eric   | 18
6  | Fred   | 42
7  | Greg   | 65
8  | Hubert | 53
9  | Irvin  | 17
10 | John   | 19
11 | Karl   | 23
```

Now, we are creating something similar to `Hashmap`(in fact, literally it is a Hash Map) which maps `id` to `address` of row with this id. Let's say:

```
id | addr 
---------
1  | @0001
2  | @0010
3  | @0011
4  | @0100
5  | @0101
6  | @0110
7  | @0111
8  | @1000
9  | @1001
10 | @1010
11 | @1011
```

So now, when I am running my query: `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE id = 8`

it will map directly `id = 8` to address in memory and the row will be returned. Of course complexity of this is `O(1)`.

So now, I have got few questions.

**1. What are the adventages and disadventages of both solutions?**

**2. Which one is more popular in current database implementations? Maybe different dbs use different approaches?**

**3. Does it exist in nonSQL dbs?**

Thank you in advance

Comment: in [tag:sql-sever] Primary Key are `Clustered Indexes` which are different from normal indexes on columns that are `Non Clustered Indexes`

Comment: You may want to ask this question in Database Administrators as you could get more knowledgeable answers.

Comment: Please do not cross-post. One question, in one site, is enough. If you posted at the wrong site, questions can be migrated.

Answer (score 2):

1. What are the adventages and disadventages of both solutions?

The second solution can not perform range scans.  It is great for selecting a single ID.  But what if you want ids 3 through 8?  It has to grab all the records individual which in the real world isn't just O(1) * 6 records to retrieve.  In a large, production database with a HashMap index you would get records on different pages, requiring you to hit the disk and read six different pages into memory.

In a B-Tree structure, like how your first situation would actually be implemented, the ids would be sequential on disk and a single page would likely hold ids 3 - 8 increasing the speed of range scans will making individual access O(log n).

1. Which one is more popular in current database implementations? Maybe different dbs use different approaches?

I don't have a huge experience in lots of different databases.  I know Sql Server uses B-Trees mostly, but SQl 2014 has some new Hash Indexes you can use on certain table.  I hear a lot of No Sql databases and caching databases built on retrieving individual records use hash indexes as well.  This makes sense for caches since you want the record for user A Page 11 and don't need range scans.

1. Does it exist in nonSQL dbs?
   Yes.  Taking a quick look at the [create index documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html) for postgressql I see it supports both Hash and B-Tree indexes as well as a few others.

Comment: this post has been moved. Could you add you answer here http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/62576/36686 ? Thank you in advance :)